# Why were the songs not translated/dubbed into German?

Tags: soundtrack, translation, dubbing, brave

When watching [*Brave*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1217209/) in German I noticed that the songs actually haven't been translated (and redubbed accordingly). Rather than that, they were just left in the original English while the rest of the film was dubbed into German.

While this is not necessarily an uncommon thing to do in musical films in general nowadays, it marks a stark departure from previous Disney practice, which always used to translate and redub the songs along with the rest of the film. This has not only been done in the past, for the more classically animated films, but also in recent times on quite similar things like *Tangled* or *Frozen* (which was released after *Brave*). *Brave* thus seems to quite stick out among the musical Disney films and I wonder why that is.

Is there any information **why they chose not to translate/dub the songs in *Brave*** along with the rest of the film in **apparent contrast to Disney tradition?** Does this even mark a move towards that practice for later films maybe?

Comment: I have no sources yet, but it might play a role that _Brave_ is a Pixar production, whilest _Frozen_ and _Tangled_ are pure Disney productions. (I know that Disney owns Pixar. However, decision processes might differ)

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia article about the [Brave soundtrack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brave_(soundtrack)#Other_versions) says

> **Differently from songs from Disney musical movies, in movies where the songs are only used as a background, Disney Character Voices International does not require for them to be dubbed**. So, in the Arabic, Cantonese, Croatian, Estonian, German, Icelandic, Japanese, Latvian, Lithuanian, Taiwanese Mandarin, Romanian, Serbian and Slovak dubs, the songs were left in English.

(highlights by me)

This suggests that [Disney Character Voices International Inc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disney_Character_Voices_International) - which is responsible for dubbing and translation - has a (more or less) strict ruleset

> musical songs get translated
>
> background songs stay in original language

However, despite the linked Wikipedia article, I could not find further resources for this rule set (yet).